# MVC how test scripts for Layout, View, Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

[image]
I was working on one page suppose to be the partial view but I design it as a single page. I include the scripts it need to work, and finish all the functionality.

```
<head>
    <title>angular-table : sortable tables with pagination for angularjs</title>
    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/angular-table.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/app_angular_cars.js"></script>
```

On the main view I declare jsTree and BlockUI. When the view load for first time, work ok create the treeview. And make an ajax call to load the partial view and angular load ok too. But then the jsTree and blockUI stop working

[image]

After some try, if I remove the `Jquery` from the Partial View, the angular table doesnt load *(even when there is a Jquery on the Layout)*, but jsTree and block continue working.

I try move all those scripts to the Layout and to the `@script section` on the main view but then the angular doesnt work.

What Im doing wrong?

Where should I include the script so every view can use angular?

And can I test Partial View alone? Or should i test it include in the project since begining?

Comment: Is your jquery version in the layout up to date? MVC might have put a very outdated version of it while scaffolding.

Comment: @Icycool I check my view-source-code there was two Jquery  included 1.10  and 2.2 I try using both for my partial view and didnt work. Still destroy jsTree and UI.block.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please keep jQuery on your partial view and try to add `jQuery.noConflict( true );` right before `<script src="/GTracker/Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>` !

Comment: You should only include one version of `jquery` or you'll need extra handling of the global variable `$`. Replace the one on top with a newer version, and remove the bottom one.

Comment: @Icycool If I remove the jquery from the partial view, the angular controller isnt created :(